# React Router Dom History goBack injecting state

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

Is there a way to use the history hook function `goBack()`, in the same way, we use the Link component?

```
<Link to={{pathname:'/brand', state: {id}} />
```

Let's say I want the user to be able to go back to a previous page with an indexed table, to a precise table page. so I will first pass the index value in the Link state component, then on the way back using `goBack()` is there a way to pass again the state in order to redirect to that specific index?

hope it's clearer now

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? The `useHistory` hook allows you to push and pop from the history stack. a `Link` pushes to the stack normally

Comment: Edited, hope it's easier to understand now.